# MIT-Scratch assets (assets for it's interface)

Tags: icons, assets, mit-scratch

I am looking for the assets for MIT-scratch. Icons inside its interface. I am creating a learn to code curriculum using scratch, and having the assets will be great for me to include into the worksheets.

I have tried googling the assets and screenshotting the interface, but the images are not clear and doing it this way is not efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scratch](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Scratch_Source_Code) is open source so you can access the assets via [Github](https://github.com/LLK/scratch-gui).

I found several in the GUI->src->components folder linked here:
https://github.com/LLK/scratch-gui/tree/develop/src/components

It appears that all icons in interface are svg files.

There are many curriculum's already available for Scratch free on web so you might want to look at others before putting a lot of time into your own.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance!
I am currently reading up on some scratch lesson plans online.
These are helpful for me to create lesson plans that integrate my robot to scratch interface